# Android Studio default company name

Tags: android, android-studio

When you create a new project in Android Studio, the default package name is `com.example.[appName]`.

Is there a way to change that `example` to `whatever` so that every new project has a default package `com.whatever.[appName]`?

Comment: When you name your package for the first time Android studio will remember the company name and will use it as the default

Comment: These claims are not true; the new project dialog lets one enter this.

Comment: @MD thanks man, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you name your package for the first time Android studio will remember the company name and will use it as the default